# angular scope assign img src will first make a bad request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my web page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="imgController">
    <img src={{imgsrc}} />
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var imgController=function($scope){
      $scope.imgsrc='http://su.bdimg.com/static/superpage/img/logo_white.png';
    };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is only an example, I want to get assign a image src via angular scope,but before angular work, the broswer will first requet the url `{{imgsrc}}`. Of course,it's a bad url, so it's a err, it's ugly, so what should i do？I will get the image resources vai angular scope, but I don't want a bad request first.

Comment: What happens if you put that script snippet above the img tag?

Comment: closed as it's not clear enough. but I think the question is clear and it's a common problem for those newbie developers who don't know why they need to use ngSrc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [ngSrc directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) which solves that problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't read the doucument seriously